# What sets the bdeleted field to 1 in the dbo.UserProfile_Full table? Is it the UPA sync timer job

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

I have deleted a user from AD, i want their user profile and mysite removed. I understand that is the role of the My Site Clean Up timer job. Although it seems the bdeleted field is never changed to 1. When i manually change bdeleted=1 and manually run the My Site Clean Up timer job it works and the user profile and mysite is removed.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the user from AD, have you started a full sync in User profile service application?

If not, you need to run a full sync via user profile service application->start profile synchronization, then check again.

Reference: [SharePoint: The complete guide to user profile cleanup – Part 3 – 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/spjr/2018/04/08/sharepoint-the-complete-guide-to-user-profile-cleanup-part-3-2013/)